# IDL not running on Ubuntu 18.04 "exec: /idl/idl1706/bin/bin.linux.x86/idl: not found"

Tags: 64-bit, executable

I have just installed IDL 7.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64. No error messages were prompted during the installation. However, when I try to run IDL on the shell, an error message is shown:

```
/idl/idl706/bin/idl: 617: exec: /idl/idl706/bin/bin.linux.x86/idl: not found
```

I have checked that the file `/idl/idl706/bin/bin.linux.x86/idl`  exists.  I have also used the `file` command for this file, and the result is:

```
idl: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
     interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Can you give me a hand with this?

Comment: Try this: Debian Science Numerical Computation packages (*science-numericalcomputation*) This metapackage will install Debian Science packages useful for numerical computation. The packages provide an array oriented  calculation and visualization system for scientific computing and data analysis. These packages are similar to commercial systems such as Matlab and IDL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I solved it by typing this in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libxcursor1:i386
sudo apt install libxinerama1:i386
sudo apt install jwm:i386
```

And now IDL is working!